# Org Agenda - Matching multiple TODO keywords in custom commands

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

This is probably pretty simple, but for some reason I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a block agenda that should list all the headlines with `NEXT` as well as `DONE` and `DROPPED` todo states. I want one block to show Done and Dropped, and another one to show NEXT.

I currently have this in `org-agenda-custom-commands`:

```
("n" "Next"
  ((tags-todo "/+DONE|+DROPPED" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Done/Dropped:")))
  (todo "NEXT" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Next:")))))
```

The `NEXT` block works, but the "Done/Dropped" block is blank. When I use this match syntax in the Agenda's actual match/search (`C-c a m`), it works, but for some reason it doesn't work in custom commands.

Perhaps some of the characters need to be escaped? I've tried various combinations of escaping with `\`, but no success so far.

Comment: Should it be todo instead of tags-todo?

Comment: Hm... I thought that there should be a way to accomplish this with tags-todo as well, but I just tried it with `todo "DONE|DROPPED"` and it seems to work. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Go ahead and post that as an answer and then accept it once the system lets you. I'm limited to my phone for a few days and won't remember to post anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can to this with a plain `tags` query just by dropping the `+` from the search:

```
("n" "Next"
  ((tags "/DONE|DROPPED" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Done/Dropped:")))
  (todo "NEXT" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Next:")))))
```

The `+` operator on a keyword or tag makes entries *require* the tag to match.  So `+DONE|+DROPPED` requires both `DONE` and `DROPPED`, which is impossible since an entries can have only one todo keyword. `+` is essential the `AND` operator.

An alternate way to do the same thing is to use the regular expression syntax: `TODO={DONE\\|DROPPED}`.  This is the only way to *avoid* a set of keywords since the search syntax doesn't allow grouping.

Comment: The issue I've had with using tags-todo is that it seems to only include active TODO keywords.  Idk what's causing it since that should only happen with "/!DONE|DROPPED".  Did you not have that issue?

Comment: @cfmg It didn't occur to me that `tags-todo` wouldn't match inactive states.  I'm editing the answer to use a `tags` query instead, which shouldn't have that issue.

Comment: Did you find it documented somewhere that this is the expexted behavior? I tried to find something about it but was unable

Comment: I don't see it documented, but `org-agenda` calls `org-tags-view` , which calls `org-search-view` which buried in its source adds `org-not-done-regexp` to the search.  So this is the designed behavior.  The docstrings all seem to feel that "TODO entry" means "not-done TODO entry"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following (per the comments above and my own testing) to do this:

```
("n" "Next"
  ((todo "DONE|DROPPED" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Done/Dropped:")))
  (todo "NEXT" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Next:")))))
```